# Div positioning to low in an HTML table

Tags: css, html, css-tables

I am facing a div positioning problem.

Here is the fiddle to depict my problem : http://jsfiddle.net/YbJ2q/11/

How can I align the red div blocks in my table cell without using the CSS property `"margin: -20px"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue lies in that you're not setting the vertical-align of your TD's to `top`.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/YbJ2q/13/

(I changed your margin-top to 10px)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Could you update the fiddle? The link above use my first example

Answer (score 3):

```
.t{
    ...
   position:relative;
    ...
} 
.handle{
    ...
    top:0px;
    ...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YbJ2q/12/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but it doesn't work on IE9 with the position:relative. The cell containing my div is adapted even if the max-width property is set.